# Como criar regexReplace para um delimitador?

Tags: java, string, regex

Tenho o seguinte conteúdo:

```java
123|321|1234\|56\|teste\||123
```

Gostaria de fazer um `regex replace` que substituísse todo `|` por quebra de linha e ignorasse o `|` escapado com `\`, desta forma eu gostaria de obter o seguinte retorno:

```java
123
321
1234|56teste|
123
```

---

*Se alguém tiver alguma alternativa que não seja `regex` também serve.*

Comment: @leogaldioli No site META temos uma [explicação resumida](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/podemos-ter-syntax-highlight-nos-codigos-como-no-so#150) de como aplicar destaque de cores ao código!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta no [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7902016/3018275), porém vou traduzir aqui:

É possível utilizar este regex:

```regex
(?:\\.|[^\|\\]++)*
```

Para pegar todo o conteúdo entre os *pipes*:

```java
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:\\\\.|[^\\|\\\\]++)*");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
    }
```

**Explicação:**

```regex
(?:        # Combina se...
 \\.       # qualquer caracter escapado
|          # ou...
 [^\|\\]++  # qualquer caracter exceto **|**
)*         # repita inúmeras vezes
```

Comment: Legal. Editei a questão e coloquei as tags de código. Veja [esta página](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) para aprender como colocar. Não é difícil.

Answer (score 6):

Eu usaria uma tradução mais direta do que foi enunciado: qualquer `|` desde que não seja precedido de `\`. Isso, em regex, é:

```regex
(?<!\\)\|
```

Com isso, você pode fazer essa substituição em uma única linha:

```java
"123|321|1234\\|56\\|teste\\||123".replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\|", "\n");
```